# How to validate Date and Time with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, date, time, datepicker

This code below is suppose to show an alert box if an incorrect date and/or time is selected.

The problem I'm having is, If I selected 25/11/2015 and choose 11:00 It shows "Please change date or Time". If I then select 25/11/2015 and choose 21:00 it shows "That's Fine".

The function is ignoring the date and just checking the time.

It should show a message saying "Please change date or time" if the user selects a time that is gone already or a date that is before today.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var today = new Date();
  var select_text = document.getElementById("datepicker-leave").value;
  var select_date = new Date(select_text);
  var select_time = document.getElementById("leavedrop").value;
  var curr_time = today.getHours() + 1;

  if ((select_date.getTime() <= today.getTime()) && select_time < curr_time) {
    alert("Please change Date or Time")
  } else {
    alert("That's Fine")
  }
}

<script>
  $(function() { //datepickers
      $( "#datepicker-leave).datepicker({            
        dateFormat: 'd-M-yy'}); 
   });
</script>
```

```html
<input type="text" id="datepicker-leave">

<select id="leavedrop">
  <option value="0">00:00</option>
  <option value="1">01:00</option>
  <option value="2">02:00</option>
  <option value="3">03:00</option>
  <option value="4">04:00</option>
  <option value="5">05:00</option>
  <option value="6">06:00</option>
  <option value="7">07:00</option>
  <option value="8">08:00</option>
  <option value="9">09:00</option>
  <option value="10">10:00</option>
  <option value="11">11:00</option>
  <option value="12">12:00</option>
  <option value="13">13:00</option>
  <option value="14">14:00</option>
  <option value="15">15:00</option>
  <option value="16">16:00</option>
  <option value="17">17:00</option>
  <option value="18">18:00</option>
  <option value="19">19:00</option>
  <option value="20">20:00</option>
  <option value="21">21:00</option>
  <option value="22">22:00</option>
  <option value="24">23:00</option>
</select>

<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="myFunction()" />
```

Comment: Consider using moment.js for all date manipulation and validation.

Comment: Why are you comparing dates.getTime()? You are not setting time in select_date. Also a pointer, for 23:00, value is 24. Also, element.value returns string. Not sure if any of this is causing issue, but you should check them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below structure for the date

```
$( "#date" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

Then try this

```
$(function() {
    $( "#date" ).datepicker({ 
     dateFormat: 'd MM, yy',
     onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
         var stop = dateText.indexOf(',');
        alert( dateText.substring(0, stop));
     }
    });
});
```

In side on select you trigger the alert.

Comment: first tell me one thing what you want exactly do you want to validate the date field or do you want to format the date field

Comment: I want it to show a alert message I select yesterdays date.

Answer (score 0):

Its not working because you are not entering date in proper format

You need to use `(YYYY-MM-DD)` format to make it work

for your example put date as `2015-11-25`

Comment: The date format I'm using is 'd-M-yy'. I'll add JQuery code

Comment: @imraanstack1 do you want to validate the text field

Answer (score 0):

It seems like date object in JavaScript is pretty weak without any additions.
I found the pretty useful library [DateJS](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation) which gives you some powerful methods to solve your problem.

Here is also a little guide from [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/2007/11/27/getting-started-with-datejs/).

For example you could use the equals method: `Date.equals(Date.today(), pickedDate());`

You have to read a little bit through the documentation to reach your goal.